# How to attach quarter-round molding to the base of a shower stall

Tags: shower

Looking to attach this quarter-round to the shower stall.
Should I glue and should there be a gap for caulk. Don’t think I can nail as concrete flooring below laminate. If gluing, should I glue to floor and caulk to stall or glue both? Worried about floor movement if glued to floor.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is that wood quarter round? I would encourage you not to use that and find PVC quarter round if you insist.

For install I would first silicone the end of the laminate gap where it butts into the pan and let it dry. Then attach the quarter round with a bead polyurethane construction adhesive to the pan only on the vertical surface, or better yet schluter kerdi-fix if you can find it. Then silicone the edges and hope there is enough allowance for movement. Ideally there would not caulk the gap with the laminate but I would be more worried about water intrusion than expansion and contraction.

Comment: +1 on PVC quarter round and schluter kerdi-fix bonded to the vertical surface of the pan! I’d also seal the top and bottom joints with a clear 100% silicone product obtained from a glass/mirror shop — not a big box store.  For something less permanent, might be possible to use 2P-10 as well.

Comment: *if you insist*, +1. Just caulk it.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't think you can get adhesive to work (I'd use construction adhesive, such as Liquid Nails), then I *would* fasten to the concrete--at least in a two or three places.

1. Using a high-speed steel bit slightly smaller than a 4d or 6d finish nail, drill through the molding at a steep angle.  Let that bit mark the flooring where it comes through, then set the trim aside.
2. Using a masonry bit, drill a 1/4" hold about 2" into the concrete at each of the marked locations.
3. Coat a 1/4" dowel segment with wood glue or epoxy and tap it into the hole in the concrete. Let the adhesive set up.
4. Replace your trim and fasten it with trim nails into the dowels. Set the nails and fill their holes with caulk or putty to prevent rust.

Alternatively, use trim-head screws and a *shallow* angle to fasten to the shower pan itself. If you pilot properly it should hold well. You could use trim screws into the floor dowels as well, but they do leave a bigger hole in the trim, so nails are preferable.

Comment: So a few piles and a ground beam.  One of the most creative answers I've seen on this site. I can't wait to try it.+1